# Pulling Values From List Python

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django and I am saving the below variable as a list:

`manifestData = form.cleaned_data`

so if I print this it returns:

`[{'ProductCode': <Product: APPLES-1>, 'UnitQty': u'11', 'Price': u'11.00', 'Amount': u'121', 'DescriptionOfGoods': u'Washington Extra Fancy', 'Type': u'Cases', u'id': None, u'DELETE': False}, {'ProductCode': <Product: ORANGES-1>, 'UnitQty': u'1', 'Price': u'12.00', 'Amount': u'12', 'DescriptionOfGoods': u'SUNKIST ORANGES', 'Type': u'Cases', u'id': None, u'DELETE': False}]`

I need to pull the `ProductCode` values out of this and save them to variables. Really I need the values APPLES-1 and ORANGES-1 pulled from the list.  What would my best approach be for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What output you are expecting?. What format value is Product code key contains`<Product: APPLES-1` this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you need to use map function:-

```py
map(lambda x: x['ProductCode'], manifestData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your `Product` model? Assuming, the model has a field as `name` you could try

```
codes = map(lambda x: x['ProductCode'].name, manifestData)
```